# KeyError in weather station project

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm getting a error like this with a weather station project I'm working on. The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wind_direction_byo.py", line 27, in <module>
    print('Unknown value: ' + str(wind) + ' ' + str(volts[wind]))
KeyError: 0.0
```

This is the source file code that i tried to execute:

```
   from gpiozero import MCP3008
import time
import math
adc = MCP3008(channel=0)
count = 0
values = []
volts = {0.4: 0.0,
         1.4: 22.5,
         1.2: 45.0,
         2.8: 67.5,
         2.7: 90.0, 
         2.9: 112.5,
         2.2: 135.0,
         2.5: 157.5, 
         1.8: 180.0, 
         2.0: 202.5, 
         0.7: 225.0, 
         0.8: 247.5, 
         0.1: 270.0, 
         0.3: 292.5, 
         0.2: 315.0, 
         0.6: 337.5}

while True:
    wind = round(adc.value*3.3,1)
    if not wind in volts:
        print('Unknown value: ' + str(wind) + ' ' + str(volts[wind]))
    else:
        print('Found: ' + str(wind) + ' ' + str(volts[wind]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You do the check if `wind` is in your `volts` dictionary, and when it is missing, you still try to access it:

```
if not wind in volts:
    print('Unknown value: ' + str(wind) + ' ' + str(volts[wind]))
```

If it is not present, you cannot access it. Remove it from your print:

```
if not wind in volts:
    print('Unknown value: ' + str(wind))
```

Comment: Makes sense, I'm just a complete noob with python still. It works now thanks.However the program does not give what its supposed to, might be my wiring, will have to look